# iOS list existing directories

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I already get path for documents directory and create some directories inside. I already know how to check if directory exist, delete it or its files but, how could I list directories? Thank you.

for file listing I use:

```
int Count;
    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeDirectoryName"];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
    for (Count = 0; Count < (int)[directoryContent count]; Count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (Count + 1), [directoryContent objectAtIndex:Count]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, this method removes all files from temporary directory of application:

```
- (void)cleatTmpDirectory
{
    // Create a local file manager instance
    NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSURL *directoryToScan = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self applicationTmpDirectory]];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = 
    [[localFileManager enumeratorAtURL:directoryToScan
            includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLIsDirectoryKey,nil]
                               options: NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles             |   
      NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | 
      NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants
                          errorHandler:nil] retain];

    NSError *error;
    // Enumerate the dirEnumerator results, each value is stored in allURLs
    for (NSURL *theURL in dirEnumerator)
    {
        // Retrieve whether a directory. 
        NSNumber *isDirectory;
        [theURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];

        if ([isDirectory boolValue] == NO)
        {
            [localFileManager removeItemAtURL:theURL error:&error];
        }
    }

    // Release the localFileManager.
    [localFileManager release];
}
```

As you can find you should use `NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator` and pass to its initialization method appropriate `keys` that you will then use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the NSDirectoryEnumerator returned by NSFileManager's `-enumeratorAtPath:` method.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: @AmiriDev Did you look at [the documentation for `-enumeratorAtPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath:)? There's an example right there.

Comment: can you please answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931224/how-to-get-the-list-of-directores-in-nsdocumentdirectory