# How to get the list of directores in NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I have created some directories in NSDocumentDirectory as

```
if (![tbxCreateFolder.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
NSArray  *arrPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryStr = [arrPaths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectoryStr stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",tbxCreateFolder.text]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){

    NSError* error;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]){

        NSLog(@"success");
        //Perfrom DB Insertation
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create MyFolder directory", [self class]);
        NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
    }
}
```

}

Now i want to get the list of directories that i have created in document folder but response is

```
NSArray *arrPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePathString = ([arrPaths count] > 0) ? [arrPaths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSLog(@"dirContents %@",basePathString);
```

Response is:

```
/Users/amir/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/7003E8D5-CCBB-4E54-896B-F4BD2F4D2CB1/Documents
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
NSString *documentDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
// create directory named "test"
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[documentDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
// retrieved all directories
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirPath error:nil]);

 NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirPath error:nil];
 BOOL isDir = NO;
 for (NSString *path in paths) {
     if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
         // path is directory
     }
}
```

Comment: that response in all files also. but i just want to get the Names of Directories.

Answer (score 3):

You could always enumerate the contents of the top level directory using `-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` like this:

```
NSFileManager *sharedFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *files = [sharedFileManager enumeratorAtPath:yourPath];

for (NSString *path in files) {
    BOOL isDirectory = NO;
    [sharedFileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory];
    if (isDirectory) {
        // you found a directory, so do what you will with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with few simple lines of code

```
NSString *documentDirectoryPath = // Initialize with Documents path
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectoryPath error:NULL];

NSMutableArray *directoriesPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *filePath in files) {
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        [directoriesPaths addObject:filePath];
    }
}

NSLog(@"directories %@", directoriesPaths);
```

Comment: can you please complete the line "NSString *documentDirectoryPath = // Initialize with Documents path
"

Comment: Sure. You already have the path to Documents directory, in your code it's `basePathString`. Add my code below yours but before that change `NSString *documentDirectoryPath = // Initialize with Documents path` to `NSString *documentDirectoryPath = basePathString`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 NSArray *arrPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *strFilePath = [[arrPath objectAtIndex:0] 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[strFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Will this list files aswell or only directories?